# Error with Copy-Item command: Cannot find drive

Tags: powershell

I have a script which backups the MongoDB database, creates an zip package and it should move this to a specified folder. But when starting `Copy-Item` it throws this exception:

> Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '"E' does not exist.

The thing is, WinRAR, the MongoDB and the whole stuff is stored on E, the backup process works just fine, only the `Copy-Item` part fails and says it cannot find E, but that's nonsense, since it can execute Programs on E...

```
Copy-Item -Path $archiveFile -Destination $localOneDriveFolder
$localOneDriveFolder = """E:\Project\Backups"""
$archiveFile = """E:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\backup_$x.rar"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the actual error message. `"E` is obviously not a valid drive identifier (notice the leading double-quote).

Remove the double-quoting:

```
$localOneDriveFolder = "E:\Project\Backups"
$archiveFile = "E:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\backup_$x.rar"
Copy-Item -Path $archiveFile -Destination $localOneDriveFolder
```